# How to make background of render texture transparent in Unity

Tags: unity, rendertexture

I am using render texture to display a model of a 3D character on a menu. I would like the background of the render texture to be made transparent. I have tried to make it transparent by editing the background color settings of the camera itself. However the color is still showing up.
[image: camera settings]
[image]

I searched for other possible solutions to fix this. One I saw was edit the HDRP setting under quality in project settings. However when I go there, the HDRP is not listed under quality. I'm not sure if it is a version issue as I am using Unity 2022. Any suggestions would be helpful.
[image: project settings]

Comment: Where are you displaying your textur is it on UI or? Could it be do to your color format?

Comment: @Ivan The texture is being displayed on only the UI. I'm using an image with the render texture as a material. I've seen it set to R32G32B32A32, but I don't seem to have that option, this is the closest I find in the color format dropdown.